# Descending pendulum motion in _physics_process

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to simulate pendulum motion within `_physics_process` as such:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var direction:Vector2
var gravity_speed=30000

onready var rod=$rod
onready var pivot:Vector2=to_global(rod.points[1])

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    var theta=Vector2(1,0).angle_to(to_local(pivot)) * -1 # angle between local x_axis & pivot point vector 
    var sin_theta=sin(theta)
    var cos_theta=cos(theta)
    
    direction.y += gravity_speed * delta
    
    direction.x= direction.x + direction.y*sin_theta*cos_theta - direction.x*cos_theta*cos_theta
    direction.y= direction.y + direction.x*sin_theta*cos_theta - direction.y*sin_theta*sin_theta
    
    direction=move_and_slide(direction,Vector2.UP)
    rod.points[1]=rod.to_local(pivot)
```

[image]

But for some reason it seems to be "falling downwards" (increased gravity so it's visible faster):
[image]

Any idea why this might be caused?

**Note:**
I'm ideally looking for a fix which involves `_physics_process()` so the object can interact with the environment as well

[Minimal](https://easyupload.io/sbberz)

**Edit:**

This is how I came up with the equation:

[image]

(theta *-1 & other -ve signs in the code because y is flipped)

---

**Edit 2: What was causing the error?**

I ran some simulations on my <strike>windows xp</strike> super computer and found out why the problem was being caused!

Turns out it's not a bug in godot but in how we deal with circular motion in physics

In physics, if we apply a tangential force *continuously* it causes the object to rotate in circular motion (emphasis on the keyword "*continuously*")

However, In godot we are **NOT** applying the tangential force *continuously* but instead apply it from frame to frame & as such our body tends to move forward tangential between those frames

Giving us an "*Err* or" from the trajectory we're suppose to be following:
[image]

This piles up in the long run and gives the illusion that the pendulum is stretching downwards:
[image]

(You can think of the universe having an infinite frame rate :P)

Comment: I haven't had the time to try your code, besides you got an answer. Anyway, I think changing the way you apply gravity would work. Notice that what we do in the code is is approximate an integration. Think of it as the sum of the motion of infinite infinitesimal steps (that is not the standard way to say it, but you get the idea). We need to pick a method that converges regardless of a variable delta. The regular formulas we often use are Euler integration, but when we have variable acceleration the result depends on the delta. In such case we use Velocity Verlet, or worst case Runge-Kutta.

Comment: Using a length constraint or a tension force (which the answer proposes) makes sense. I'm now thinking that perhaps doing it without that would only be easier if you made the motion parametric (in particular, if you could compute from the elapsed time since the start of the motion where the weight should be, then you could directly move it there for the new time).

Comment: @Theraot I had a similar idea that we could pre-calculate where it needs to be and then place it there after the elapsed time `delta` but the problem was that, that technique would require me to directly change the `global_position` of the kinematic body but the documentations says [`you should not set its position property directly.`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_kinematic_body_2d.html)

Comment: You can compute what is the velocity you need to tell it to move such that after delta it ends up where you want.

Comment: @Theraot but for that wouldn't I need to know what the delta value is _going_ to be for the next frame? because then I would know after what amount of time the next `_physics_process()` is going to be called and hence set it's velocity accordingly

Comment: No, you don't. You are not asked to simulate the next frame. Instead of setting the `global_position` to some `desired_global_position` you make a `velocity` that is `(desired_global_position - global_position) / delta` and give it to `move_and_slide`, when Godot multiplies by `delta` it gets the displacement you want.

Comment: @Theraot How would you get the `desired_global_position`?

Comment: You can use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Small-angle_approximation given the current angle and delta time, it gives you the new angle, then compute the new position given that new angle and the length of the rod. Edit: I'm wondering if it is good enough to do it with delta time, or you should keep track of the total elapsed time.

Comment: If you need to track elapsed time, a member variable can be used, in `_physics_process`, `time += delta`. `delta` is the time since the last frame was rendered in seconds, but `_physics_process` is called once per frame, so it will always be 1/framerate. I am not sure how rounding errors will affect this kind of timer. Tracking the time since the object was created with `Time.get_ticks_msec( )` may be more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution. What was missing from this simulation was the tension force from the rod, in the direction of the pivot. The `rod_length` is calculated `onready` and is set from the starting distance, but it can be set manually or changed during runtime. I did have to add air resistance (which must be negative), because once the bug was fixed the pendulum no longer lost speed.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var direction:Vector2
var gravity_speed=6000 #30000
var air_resistance = -200

onready var rod=$rod
onready var pivot:Vector2=to_global(rod.points[1])
onready var rod_length = get_position().distance_to(pivot)

func _physics_process(delta):
    direction=move_and_slide(direction,Vector2.UP)
    
    #gravity
    direction.y += gravity_speed * delta
    
    #air resistance
    direction += (direction.normalized() * air_resistance * delta).limit_length(direction.length())
    
    #pendulum motion
    var theta=Vector2(1,0).angle_to(to_local(pivot)) * -1 # angle between local x_axis & pivot point vector 
    var sin_theta=sin(theta)
    var cos_theta=cos(theta)
    direction.x= direction.x + direction.y*sin_theta*cos_theta - direction.x*cos_theta*cos_theta
    direction.y= direction.y + direction.x*sin_theta*cos_theta - direction.y*sin_theta*sin_theta
    
    #tension
    var tension = clamp(get_position().distance_to(pivot) - rod_length, 0, 1) * gravity_speed
    direction += get_position().direction_to(pivot) * tension * delta
    
    rod.points[1]=rod.to_local(pivot)
```

I am not sure exactly what was causing the issue, but the same issue persists if you do tension before pendulum motion, and a different issue appears if you do pendulum motion before air resistance or gravity.

I like this code a lot, but it may be worth noting a similar effect could be created by linking a `StaticBody2D` and a `RigidBody2D` with a `PinJoint2D` if one just needed a swinging object.

Comment: **Thanks a million! you saved me a week of headache**, my physics is a little rusty :P and you're right the same effect can be achieved with a `StaticBody2D` & a `PintJoint2D` but for that I'd have to make my controllable character inherit from `RigidBody2D` (which is a whole other pain) Oh and you might want to change `.limit_length()` to `.clamped()` since it's giving a deprecated warning

Comment: I don't think there is a call to `limit_length` in this code.

Comment: `direction += (direction.normalized() * air_resistance * delta).limit_length(direction.length())`

Comment: I would gladly edit the post to correct that if the post had a call to `limit_length`. Did you type that when porting the code?

Comment: oh sorry I meant to type "change `.clamped()` to `.limit_length()`"

Comment: Oh man I had it backwards too then. I can't remember which one I'm supposed to use.

Comment: I've been tinkering with your code but I can't seem to understand what you've done exactly, I tried [this](https://pastecode.io/s/hbfun351) from what I did understand and it seems to work, but I don't get why you've added `clamp()` and multiplied by `* gravity_speed * delta`, could you maybe explain with the recent edit I've made? :)

Comment: @cak3_lover Imagine the rod as an elastic, that when stretched has a restoring force that pulls the weight. This restoring force is proportional to how much the rod stretched. And, of course, it would be modeled as an acceleration that opposes gravity. In this case it is using the same values you used for gravity, so we can expect it to be balanced. Edit: Imagine the code allowed the restoring force to be much stronger, the weight would bounce back up and you end up with chaotic motion. Also imagine the restoring force was much weaker, then it won't prevent the stretching.

Comment: @Theraot Ah now I understand why we multiplied gravity but I still don't understand why we `clamped()` that value between 0 & 1?

Comment: @cak3_lover `tension` will have a value between `0` and `gravity_speed`.